# switch Tab in VB on button click

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I am creating tabs with div and javascript

```
<div  id="tabs"> 
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Issue Part</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Return Part</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" > Content </div>
   <div id="tabs-2" > Content </div>

</div>
```

In tab1 and tab2 I have gridview and search buttons, when I click search button on tab 2, it filters the data of gridview2 on tab2 but displays tab1 how can I explicitly add after button click to show tab2

Button Click Code

```
    Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
        Dim DataView As New DataView(PopulatePR())
        If (DropDownList2.Text = "OR") Then
            DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' OR Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
        Else
            DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' AND Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
        End If
        GridView2.DataSource = DataView
        GridView2.DataBind()

End Sub
```

I tried with this but it is not working

```
  MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Issue_Parts),"TabToSelect", "$('#tabs').tabs({ active:1})", True)
```

Comment: Can you share the buttonClick Function?

Comment: Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
        Dim DataView As New DataView(PopulatePR())
        If (DropDownList2.Text = "OR") Then
            DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' OR Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
        Else
            DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' AND Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
        End If
        GridView2.DataSource = DataView
        GridView2.DataBind()
End Sub

Comment: Add it to your original question not in comments.

Comment: Yes I have added it, please check

Comment: There is no code here that is selecting tab 1 after populating data. Are you sure somewhere is dataGridView events there isn't some code that is selecting tab 1? Because it is not possible for the program to do it on its own.

Comment: I want code that will redirect to tab 2. When gridview populates on tab 2 after clicking search button, on browser tab1 comes

Comment: I see the button is on tab1. The question gave the impression that the button is on tab2 and after populating the grid on tab 2 it goes to tab1 for no obvious reason. But the solution I provided will work. See my answer.

Comment: No I have two tabs each has search button and gridview. when I click search button on tab 2, it populates gridview on tab2 but on browser by default, when page loads, tab1 is open

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere in the control events of the dataGridView tab 1 is being selected. Since it is not possible for the program to do it on its on accord. I strongly recommend that you find where that piece of code is that is causing the bug.

As for how you can explicitly select tab 2. You do it by using the added line I did to select tab2 within you ButtonClick event. But this is just a kludge for time being. It is once again strongly recommended to find the piece of code that is selecting tab1.

```
    Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
          Dim DataView As New DataView(PopulatePR())
          If (DropDownList2.Text = "OR") Then
              DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' OR Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
          Else
              DataView.RowFilter = "Case = '" + Txtcase1.Text + "' AND Name = '" + txtname1.Text + "'"
          End If
          GridView2.DataSource = DataView
          GridView2.DataBind()
          tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2
    End Sub
```

Comment: but I am not using tabcontrol I have made tabs with div